# Sorted Maps for Repeating values

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I have an xml that looks like :

```
<Order OrderNo="1">
 <OrderLines LineNo="1" Qty="10"/>
 <OrderLines LineNo="2" Qty="7"/>
 <OrderLines LineNo="3" Qty="10"/>
 <OrderLines LineNo="4" Qty="4"/>
 <OrderLines LineNo="5" Qty="1"/>
</OrderLines>
</Order>
```

I need to store the OrderLines in a map based on descending value of qty. 
I was thinking about a TreeMap, but then it expects only unique values for keys. In my case, the Qty can be same for multiple lines.

I am thinking about having the Qty as Key and it may not be unique.

Any help on this anyone?

Comment: Can you specify: do you need keys to be unique, or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java)

Comment: Just wanna add same link as @BurakAkyıldız dose. If you not find answer there, please, write your concerns.

Comment: so i want map my to look like :

    <Qty 10, Line 1>
    <Qty 10, Line 3>
    <Qty 7, Line 2>
    <Qty 4, Line 4>
    <Qty 1, Line 5>

Comment: @SMA_JAVA thats just make no sense. How could you get values then? What's you expect as output in `get(10)` in your code?

Comment: Since I am expecting this map to be sorted in descending order, my first value will always be the maximum value for Qty. I will just always take first entry from the map (the max value for Qty). 
I dont really want to do a get(10).

Comment: Then why you need a whole map for that? You could just store `maxValue`, or store both *LineNo* and *Qty*.

Comment: I am not sure I entirely got what you said. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143264/discussion-between-sergey-and-sma-java).